# How to Show Module List in VS Code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

So I just started coding with vs code, and curious about how to keep showing this module list. Because it's going to help me so much to define what I must be supposed to code after the module before.

How to show this list?

[image: screenshot of list]

Comment: Use extension `PyLance`

Answer (score 1):

That is called [intelliSense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense) and you have to download it to enjoy it :)

Answer (score 1):

also there are some AI powered auto complete tools :

1. [TabNine](https://www.tabnine.com/)
2. [GitHub Copilot](https://copilot.github.com/)
3. [Kite](https://www.kite.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This is IntelliSense, a function of vscode.

IntelliSense is a general term for various code editing features including: code completion, parameter info, quick info, and member lists. IntelliSense features are sometimes called by other names such as "code completion", "content assist", and "code hinting."

You could install the extension and get code tips.

You can also refer to the [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense) of vscode for more details.